# Switch content types in Sharepoint 2007 list

Tags: list, sharepoint-2007, contenttype

In Sharepoint 2007 I have a list with 2 content types set up (A & B), allowing for different form versions to be presented per content type.

Is it possible for a user to now view/edit a content type A record using content type B column settings?

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed the 'Content Type' field at the top of the edit form .... that's what I needed.